# How can I passing multiple Cypress environment variable in CLI?

Tags: javascript, cypress, command-line-interface

I have the following configuration in my Cypress cypress.config.js

```
 env: {
    baseUrl: "https://home.abc.com",
    token_url: "https://home.abc.com/api/token",
    username: "",
    password: ""
  },
```

However, when I pass the following command in CLI, it always results in an unauthorized issue from my endpoints.

`yarn cypress run --env username=admin,password=samplepassword`

Things work great when I directly assign a username and password with its value inside the config file but I trying to store credential details inside my code.

I tried to pass only **one** environment variable for testing and it work perfectly.

*cypress.config.js*

```
 env: {
    baseUrl: "https://home.abc.com",
    token_url: "https://home.abc.com/api/token",
    username: "",
    password: "samplepassword"
  },
```

*CLI Command*
`yarn cypress run --env username=admin`

Comment: In my attempt, the username and password are being passed from command line into the test. What version of Cypress are you running?

Answer (score 0):

**As the first option, You can define all your required environments in a config file and call them inside your tests the following way:**

```
Cypress.env('variableName')
```

Or if you have a set of different credentials for different environments (production, dev, test) you can create  a separate configuration file for each of them the following way:

**cypress.config.js**

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const file = config.env.configFile;
      const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve(
        '.',
        'cypress/plugins/configs',
        `${file}.json`
      );
      return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile);
    },
  },
});
```

**Create a separate config file with the structure you like, for example:**

```
{
  "baseUrl": "www.yourwebsite.com",
  "env": {
    "failSilently": false,
    "updateSnapshots": false
  },
  "account": {
    "login": "admin",
    "username": "123@something.com",
    "password": "pass123",
  }
}
```

**Then you can run your tests this way:**

```
npm run --env configFile=prod,TAGS=@prod
```

**And use all your configuration settings in tests:**

```
Cypress.config().account.username;
```

**If you need to pass credentials with CLI try this way:**

```
npx cypress run PRO_USERNAME='CypTest2',PRO_PASSWORD='CypTest123' --headless --browser chrome
```

These variables can be stored in configuration file with tdefault values but in this case you override their values.

Comment: Thanks, @Valeriia however my requirement is not to hardcode the credentials onto the config file

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it will help you